# html css, what's wrong in my code?

Tags: html, css

Here is a simple HTML/CSS page in which I put a div container (class="container") with `min-height: 500px;` and `background-color: orange;`

This div container extends with no limit when I put written content (paragraphs ). However, when I put my DIVS it stops at `500px height`.
Can you please tell me why?
Regards

```css
.container{
    width: 960px;
 min-height: 500px;
 background-color: orange;
}

.box{
    width: 290px;
 min-height: 300px;
 background-color: blue;
 margin-left: 20px;
 margin-bottom: 20px;
 float: left;
}

.box:hover{
    width: 290px;
 min-height: 300px;
 background-color: black;
 margin-left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr">
<head>
<meta chaset="utf-8" />
<title>Test DIVs</title>

</head>
<body>
    <div class="container"> 

        <div class="box"></div>
 <div class="box"></div>
 <div class="box"></div> 
 <div class="box"></div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is because your divs are floated and they do not affect parent's height so it's by default triggered to it's `min-height`. Add additional div like this one:

```
<div class="clearfix"></div>
```

and this css:

```
.clearfix:after { 
   content: " ";
   display: block; 
   height: 0; 
   clear: both;
}
```

> What `.clearfix` does is to force content after the floats or the
>   container containing the floats to render below it.

Try it in the snippet:

```css
.container{
    width: 960px;
 /* min-height: 500px; */
 background-color: orange;
    height: auto;
}

.box{
    width: 290px;
 min-height: 300px;
 background-color: blue;
 margin-left: 20px;
 margin-bottom: 20px;
 float: left;
}

.box:hover{
    width: 290px;
 min-height: 300px;
 background-color: black;
 margin-left: 20px;
}

.clearfix:after { 
   content: " ";
   display: block; 
   height: 0; 
   clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div class="container"> 

  <div class="box">
  </div>
  
  <div class="box">
  </div>
  
  <div class="box"> 
  </div>
  
  <div class="box">
  </div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Thanks :-) this additional div fixed the bug!

Answer (score 0):

The reason your container div is not covering the box divs is because you have the box div's set at a float.

To combat this add:

```
    <div style="clear: both"></div>
```

Below the floating elements.

Answer (score 0):

Use `display:inline-block;` instead of `float:left;` and it will just work fine.

```
.box{
    width: 290px;
    min-height: 300px;
    background-color: blue;
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    display:inline-block;
}
```